# Как отправлять файлы с компьютера через телеграм api весом более 50 мегабайт [PYTHON]

Tags: python, файлы, api, telegram

У меня возникла проблема - я не знаю как отправить видео весом более 50мб, всегда пишет что размер слишком большой - я отправляю как document. Пробовал разные файлообменники - во всех не выходило.

Comment: У бота лимит на новые файлы- 50 МВ. https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files  Но есть нюанс - https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#using-a-local-bot-api-server

Comment: Других вариантов нету?